# How do I know if a form has been modified

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I Would like to know if there is anyway I can check if a form has been modified.

eg. If one of the inputs has been changed I would like to display a button to submit the changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a "change" event with JQuery. So doing something like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').change(function() {
        # Here you display your button
    }
}
```

Will perfectly work (and your javascript remains independant from your html).

Comment: So simple!  I love jQuery!

Answer (score 4):

There is a attribute called: `onchange="JAVASCRIPTFUNCTION();"`

**JavaScript Example:**

```
<form onchange="displayButton();"> </form>
```

.

**Full explaination:** [CLICK](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) *(w3schools.com is one of the best resources out there)*

// // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // // //

**jQuery Example:**

```
$(FORM_ID).change(function(){
    $(BUTTON_ID).show();
});
```

Comment: this is javascript approach not actually jquery

Comment: @Stamper, right, but i thought doing it by native js is much more easier.

Comment: @daemonfire300- ? how would you think that? but even that the OP asked for jquery. but I didnt downvote you

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you could use the on change event.

```
$('#form_id input').change(function(){
    $('#button').show();
});
```

The button can be hidden in the meantime.