# Aurelia - Custom validation to check if a form has changes

Tags: aurelia

I see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600906/how-do-i-know-if-a-form-has-been-modified) question regarding whether the form I am validating has changed.

However it has nothing to do with Aurelia validation and I would like to validate whether the form has any changes upon clicking the save button. I dont want to do it on the server.

What I have done is to save the values I fetched initially so I can do a comparison.

```
        fetch("/api/Client/editClient/" + parms.id, {
            method: "GET",
            headers
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.client.deserialize(data);
                this.originalClient === this.client;
            })
```

original client is the unmodified object.

I have created a custom validation function however its not working as intended.

I thought I could use the current value and then compare it to the original value.

```
    ValidationRules.customRule(
        'changesExist',
        (value, obj, fetchedEntity) =>
            fetchedEntity != value,
        'No changes detected'
    );
```

When I try and use it I find it erroring:

```
    // Validation Rules.
    ValidationRules
        .ensure(a: ClientDetails) => a).satisfiesRule('changesExist', this.originalClient);
```

I am unsure how to make this work. What I want is a validation that compares the orginalClient object with the the one that is to be sent back to the server.  This way I can check if there is reason for sending it back can saving it to the database...

Comment: What does `this.client.deserialize(data);` do? Also why do you do this: `this.originalClient === this.client;`?

Anyhow, this line `fetchedEntity != value` does an _object reference comparison_.

Comment: With regard to the deserialize I was under the impression I needed to do that so that I could apply it to the form. Its in the activate function. I wanted the two objects to be compared. That is therefore wrong. I need a copy of the fetched data so i can compare the two at the end.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I wanted to point you towards.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather brute force, but this will likely do what you want:

```
 JSON.stringify(fetchedEntity) !== JSON.stringify(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [app-contacts](https://github.com/aurelia/app-contacts) sample app does it using an `areEqual` function. Have a look at the repo and you can see how it's used and how you could adapt it for your purposes.

```
function areEqual(obj1, obj2) {
    return Object.keys(obj1).every((key) => obj2.hasOwnProperty(key) && (obj1[key] === obj2[key]));
};
```